# Paint removal from metal

Tags: metallurgy

What chemical product works well to strip paint off to reveal bare metal in this instance a small tin (guessing to be aluminium or steel) with as good a finish as possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

N-Methyl-2-pyrrolidone - typical paint stripper.